# Unity NUnit tests failing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

My tests were all running yesterday but today they all fail. I tried making a new test class and just running an empty test but that fails as well. I have no idea what's going on. Here's the stack trace:

```
ERROR: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController+LoadTestsAction..ctor (NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController controller, System.Object handler)[0x00008] in <116d15b838ac4e24a87624af132b3294>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod, object, object[], System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---


Server stack trace: 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0000f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:667 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:652 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:680 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00213] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5419 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x000ae] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:107 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyString, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityInfo, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00077] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:365 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityInfo) [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:278 
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityAttributes) [0x0000e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:391 
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstance(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityAttributes) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:412 
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at(wrapper xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(object, byte[]&, byte[]&, string, string, bool)

Exception rethrown at[0]: 
  at(wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(System.String typeName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(System.String testAssemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey, TValue] settings) [0x000a1] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage() [0x0007a] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.TestDomainRunner.LoadPackage() [0x00017] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load() [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.LoadPackage() [0x0001d] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded() [0x00008] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter filter) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.NUnit.Engine.ITestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter filter) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit3Runner.NUnitTestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, System.String[] nameFilter, System.String path, System.String suiteName, System.String[] supportAssemblies, System.String testRunnerType, System.String testRunnerAssembly) [0x00076] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnit3Runner/NUnitTestRunner.cs:129 
  at NUnit3Runner.NUnitTestRunner.Run(MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.RunRequest r) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnit3Runner/NUnitTestRunner.cs:72 
  at(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod, object, object[], System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController+LoadTestsAction..ctor (NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController controller, System.Object handler)[0x00008] in <116d15b838ac4e24a87624af132b3294>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod, object, object[], System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---


Server stack trace: 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0000f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:667 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke(System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:652 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:680 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00213] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5419 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x000ae] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:107 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyString, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityInfo, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00077] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:365 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityInfo) [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:278 
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityAttributes) [0x0000e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:391 
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstance(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityAttributes) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:412 
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at(wrapper xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(object, byte[]&, byte[]&, string, string, bool)

Exception rethrown at[0]: 
  at(wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string, bool, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(System.String typeName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(System.String testAssemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey, TValue] settings) [0x000a1] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage() [0x0007a] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.TestDomainRunner.LoadPackage() [0x00017] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load() [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.LoadPackage() [0x0001d] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded() [0x00008] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter filter) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.NUnit.Engine.ITestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter filter) [0x00000] in <7934713e6a5945a48b191c3250979bc9>:0 
  at NUnit3Runner.NUnitTestRunner.Run(NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, System.String[] nameFilter, System.String path, System.String suiteName, System.String[] supportAssemblies, System.String testRunnerType, System.String testRunnerAssembly) [0x00076] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnit3Runner/NUnitTestRunner.cs:129 
  at NUnit3Runner.NUnitTestRunner.Run(MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.RunRequest r) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnit3Runner/NUnitTestRunner.cs:72 
  at(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod, object, object[], System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

Does anyone know why my tests might be failing? The contents of the test class are just an empty file, with a test method stub. Surely you don't need to see an empty method stub here? You can replicate the exact same file by going to Unity -> new edit mode script, and then not modifying the generated file. My project builds fine and the tests are bing run in Debug mode. Any ideas?

Update

If I create test scripts with Unity and run them with monodevelop, they work fine. I'm using Unity Collaborate. They werent running with either Rider or Visual Studio. Maybe it's because Unity Collaborate doesn't work with IDE's other than Monodevelop? Is there some kind of project setting I have to set?

Comment: If you show your test stub code, then somebody without Unity can possibly answer you - like the nunit team guys. It's unlikely that anyone will install unity just to see what kind of stub it generates.